# How to do exponentiation in clojure?

Tags: clojure, exponentiation

How can I do exponentiation in clojure?
For now I'm only needing integer exponentiation, but the question goes for fractions too.

Comment: As someone who doesn't know clojure, but is predisposed to like it (being a fan of lisps, functional programming, and having lots of handy libraries), I'm disappointed that this simple question has so many answers--or that it had to be asked at all.  I would have thought that exponentiation would just be one of the basic functions provided without having to do anything at all special.  I'm glad it was asked, though.

Comment: well yes probably some version of it should be in the core... but i think that many answers is still a good sign. the "multiple paths to implementation" seems to be the reason a lot of these things aren't provided -- the user should know the details of the function they are using for efficiency's sake. for example (as is pointed out in the chosen answer) some ways may potentially blow the stack, others less likely to do so. maybe some are lazy, some eager... all details that need to be paid some attention in Clojure, which is why I feel most non-trivial libs aren't provided due to philosophy

Comment: I think the reason there's not just an exp function in the core is because clojure's numeric tower is badly broken for efficiency reasons. So there are all sorts of different things you could mean by exponentiation. What should (exp 2 (exp 2 200)) be? An error or a huge integer that takes an age to calculate? If you just want the usual floating point exp, then the java one is built in. If you want a language where the numbers do their best to act like the reals, and hang the cost, use scheme instead of clojure.

Answer (score 157, accepted):

classic recursion (watch this, it blows stack)

```
(defn exp [x n]
     (if (zero? n) 1
         (* x (exp x (dec n)))))
```

tail recursion

```
(defn exp [x n]
  (loop [acc 1 n n]
    (if (zero? n) acc
        (recur (* x acc) (dec n)))))
```

functional

```
(defn exp [x n]
  (reduce * (repeat n x)))
```

sneaky (also blows stack, but not so easily)

```
(defn exp-s [x n]
  (let [square (fn[x] (* x x))]
    (cond (zero? n) 1
          (even? n) (square (exp-s x (/ n 2)))
          :else (* x (exp-s x (dec n))))))
```

library

```
(require 'clojure.contrib.math)
```

Comment: see fully iterative version of sneaky solution below http://stackoverflow.com/a/22977674/231589

Comment: Clojure.contrib.math is now deprecated, see [Math.Numeric-Tower](https://github.com/clojure/math.numeric-tower)

Comment: The second suggestion (tail recursive) has integer overflow for n < 0.

Comment: Fantastic answer. Here's how to do with it with a macro: (defmacro exp [x n]
  `(* ~@(take n (repeat x))))

Comment: Terminal recursion for the fast exponentiation algorithm: `(def exp (letfn [(rexp [x n r] (cond (zero? n) r (even? n) (recur (*' x x) (/ n 2) r) :else (recur (*' x x) (/ (dec n) 2) (*' x r))))] (fn [x n] (rexp x n 1))))`. It never blows the stack. Test `(exp 1 (exp 2 30000))`

Comment: None of the answers that involve importing an existing function work (including the `(require 'clojure.contrib.math)` in this answer). But `(defn exp [x n] (reduce * (repeat n x)))` works great, and is easy to understand!

Comment: Clojure has no "tail recursion" (or rather, ["tail-call optimization"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call)) because Java does have it. A loop, however, is a loop.

Answer (score 84):

Clojure has a power function that works well: I'd recommend using this rather than going via Java interop since it handles all the Clojure arbitrary-precision number types correctly. It is in namespace [clojure.math.numeric-tower](https://github.com/clojure/math.numeric-tower).

It's called `expt` for *exponentiation* rather than `power` or `pow` which maybe explains why it's a bit hard to find ... anyway here's a small example (note that `use` works but better use [`require`](https://stuartsierra.com/2016/clojure-how-to-ns.html)):

```
(require '[clojure.math.numeric-tower :as math :refer [expt]])  ; as of Clojure 1.3
;; (use 'clojure.contrib.math)     ; before Clojure 1.3
```

```
(expt 2 200)
=> 1606938044258990275541962092341162602522202993782792835301376
```

## Reminder about package installation

You must first install the Java package `org.clojure.math.numeric-tower` to make the Clojure namespace `clojure.math.numeric-tower` accessible!

On the command line:

```
$ lein new my-example-project
$ cd lein new my-example-project
```

Then edit `project.clj` and add `[org.clojure/math.numeric-tower "0.0.4"]` to the dependencies vector.

Start a lein REPL (not a clojure REPL)

```
$ lein repl
```

Now:

```
(require '[clojure.math.numeric-tower :as math])
(math/expt 4 2)
;=> 16
```

or

```
(require '[clojure.math.numeric-tower :as math :refer [expt]])
(expt 4 2)
;=> 16
```

Comment: Probably unknown because it doesn't appear to be part of standard Clojure.  1.3.0 tosses errors about not being able to locate the math.clj when I try to do it this way.

Comment: I think it's now in "clojure.math.numeric-tower" as of 1.3 (since clojure.contrib got broken up into individual libraries)

Comment: Added "reminder about package installation" to allay user frustration.

Answer (score 73):

You can use java's `Math.pow` or `BigInteger.pow` methods:

```
(Math/pow base exponent)

(.pow (bigdec base) exponent)
```

Comment: +1, though I know you can interop with java libs; however, 1) Math.pow works with doubles, I need Integers, can you give an example? 2) Do you really have to use interop for sth. simple as powers?

Comment: Clojure is built arround the java libraries, it does not attempt to fix what is not broken and Math/pow works just fine.
Why do you need to care for doubles or integers?
You could also use this http://richhickey.github.com/clojure-contrib/generic.math-functions-api.html

Comment: @Peter: 1) Unless your powers are so large that they can't be accurately represented by doubles anymore, there really is no problem with just casting the result to int. 2) I don't see how writing `Math/pow` is more complicated than `math-pow` or whatever the name would be if there was a clojure equivalent. If there already is a simple java method that does what you want, there is no reason to recreate the functionality in clojure. Java interop is not inherently harmful.

Comment: @Da vinci : strange remark, it's a language of it's own, and has a lot of functions that are in Java (like stringreverse)

Comment: @sepp : It is indeed about big nummers (project euler like stuff)

Comment: @Peter: For bigints you can use java's BigInteger.pow instance method.

Comment: I think you are better using Clojure's clojure.contrib.math/expt if you want accurate biginteger powers. Probably does the same under the hood but much nicer than going via Java interop.....

Comment: I'm getting `No matching method pow ... for class clojure.lang.BigInt` -- shouldn't it be `(.pow (biginteger base) exponent)`?

Answer (score 15):

When this question was originally asked, [clojure.contrib.math/expt](http://clojure.github.com/clojure-contrib/math-api.html#clojure.contrib.math/expt) was the official library function to do this. Since then, it has moved to [clojure.math.numeric-tower](https://github.com/clojure/math.numeric-tower/blob/46a91e5/src/main/clojure/clojure/math/numeric_tower.clj#L80)

Comment: +1 for this answer since it handles all the Clojure exact (i.e. BigDecimal / BigInteger) arithmetic correctly.

Answer (score 9):

```
user=> (.pow (BigInteger. "2") 10)
1024
user=> (.pow (BigInteger. "2") 100)
1267650600228229401496703205376
```

Comment: also you can use the literal notation for this: `(.pow 2M 100)`

Comment: Their types are different. user=> (type 2M)
java.math.BigDecimal
user=> (type (BigInteger. "2"))
java.math.BigInteger

Comment: imo best solution, showr, using existing libraries, and including handling of bigint. +1

Comment: For me `(Math/pow Math/E x)` does the trick (replacing `Math/E` with the base of your choice).

Answer (score 6):

If you really need a function and not a method you can simply wrap it:

```
 (defn pow [b e] (Math/pow b e))
```

And in this function you can cast it to `int` or similar. Functions are often more useful that methods because you can pass them as parameters to another functions - in this case `map` comes to my mind.

If you really need to avoid Java interop, you can write your own power function. For example, this is a simple function:

```
 (defn pow [n p] (let [result (apply * (take (abs p) (cycle [n])))]
   (if (neg? p) (/ 1 result) result)))
```

That calculates power for integer exponent (i.e. no roots).

Also, if you are dealing with *large* numbers, you may want to use `BigInteger` instead of `int`.

And if you are dealing with *very large* numbers, you may want to express them as lists of digits, and write your own arithmetic functions to stream over them as they calculate the result and output the result to some other stream.

Answer (score 6):

Since Clojure 1.11, `clojure.math/pow` ships with the [standard library](https://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.math-api.html#clojure.math/pow), and works both for Clojure and ClojureScript.

Answer (score 4):

I think this would work too:

```
(defn expt [x pow] (apply * (repeat pow x)))
```

Comment: but seems to max out at 2^63... def not capable of 2^200

Answer (score 4):

[SICP inspired](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-11.html#%_thm_1.16) full iterative fast version of 'sneaky' implementation above.

```
(defn fast-expt-iter [b n]
  (let [inner (fn [a b n]
                (cond
                  (= n 0) a
                  (even? n) (recur a (* b b) (/ n 2))
                  :else (recur (* a b) b (- n 1))))
        ]
    (inner 1 b n)))
```

Answer (score 3):

Implementation of "sneaky" method with tail recursion and supporting negative exponent:

```
(defn exp
  "exponent of x^n (int n only), with tail recursion and O(logn)"
   [x n]
   (if (< n 0)
     (/ 1 (exp x (- n)))
     (loop [acc 1
            base x
            pow n]
       (if (= pow 0)
         acc                           
         (if (even? pow)
           (recur acc (* base base) (/ pow 2))
           (recur  (* acc base) base (dec pow)))))))
```

Answer (score 3):

A simple one-liner using reduce:

```
(defn pow [a b] (reduce * 1 (repeat b a)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`clojure.math.numeric-tower`](https://github.com/clojure/math.numeric-tower), formerly `clojure.contrib.math`.

---

[API Documentation](http://clojure.github.io/math.numeric-tower/)

---

```
(ns user
  (:require [clojure.math.numeric-tower :as m]))

(defn- sqr
  "Uses the numeric tower expt to square a number"
  [x]
  (m/expt x 2))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
(defn pow [x n]
  (loop [x x n n r 1]
    (cond
      (= n 0) r
      (even? n) (recur (* x x) (/ n 2) r)
      :else (recur x (dec n) (* r x)))))
```

for a tail-recursive O(log n) solution, if you want to implement it yourself (only supports positive integers).  Obviously, the better solution is to use the library functions that others have pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

I personally use:

```
(defn pow [x n] (reduce *' (repeat n x)))
```

Notice the apostrophe (') after the asterisk.

Works well for all sizes of integers.

Note: This might be a little slow for some implementations.
(time (pow 2 200000)) took 1.2 seconds to resolve on my system.

Answer (score 0):

How about clojure.contrib.genric.math-functions

There is a pow function in the clojure.contrib.generic.math-functions library.  It is just a macro to Math.pow and is more of a "clojureish" way of calling the Java math function.

http://clojure.github.com/clojure-contrib/generic.math-functions-api.html#clojure.contrib.generic.math-functions/pow

Comment: ["Note - the contrib libs have moved to individual repos under Clojure org"](https://github.com/richhickey/clojure-contrib); this answer is outdated.