# How to use expt function in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, dependencies, leiningen, read-eval-print-loop

I am trying to use `expt` function according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5078575/215094) but when I try to do `(use 'clojure.math.numeric-tower)` in REPL I get the error

```
user> (use 'clojure.math.numeric-tower)
(use 'clojure.math.numeric-tower)FileNotFoundException Could not locate clojure/math/numeric_tower__init.class or clojure/math/numeric_tower.clj on classpath:   clojure.lang.RT.load (RT.java:443)
```

I thought I needed to put Leiningen dependency information as explained [here](https://github.com/clojure/math.numeric-tower)

```
[org.clojure/math.numeric-tower "0.0.2"]
```

in my `project.clj`, and I did that but I still get the same error. What am I doing wrong?

---

**EDIT**

[As in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11641372/how-can-new-clojure-libraries-be-loaded-in-the-repl) I went to my project directory and did `lein deps`

```
a@b:~/command-line-args$ lein deps
Retrieving org/clojure/math.numeric-tower/0.0.2/math.numeric-tower-0.0.2.pom from central
Retrieving org/clojure/math.numeric-tower/0.0.2/math.numeric-tower-0.0.2.jar from central
a@b:~/command-line-args$
```

but I still get the same error in REPL.

---

**Edit2**

As per Vidya's answer I am trying to use Pomegranate but without success. This is what I tried. What am I doing wrong:

```
user> (use '[cemerick.pomegranate :only (add-dependencies)])
nil
user> (add-dependencies :coordinate '[[org.clojure/math.numeric-tower "0.0.2"]]
                        :repositories (merge cemerick.pomegranate.aether/maven-central
                                             {"clojars" "http://clojars.org/repo"}))
{}
user> (require '(numeric-tower core stats charts))
FileNotFoundException Could not locate numeric_tower/core__init.class or numeric_tower/core.clj on classpath:   clojure.lang.RT.load (RT.java:443)
user> (require 'clojure.contrib.math)
FileNotFoundException Could not locate clojure/contrib/math__init.class or clojure/contrib/math.clj on classpath:   clojure.lang.RT.load (RT.java:443)
user>
```

Comment: did you restart your repl after changing your deps? deps are only found at startup time

Comment: Everything looks fine. Have you also restarted your REPL?

Comment: Yes, I restarted the REPL.

Comment: And I did `lein deps` in my project directory and I still get the same error in REPL (See the edit to my question).

Comment: Did you execute lein repl from the project directory?

Comment: No, I was trying to do this in REPL in emacs. I did in leiningen REPL and it worked. How do I use this library in emacs REPL? I opened a clojure file in `/src` and I did `C-c C-k` and then `C-c M-n` and tried to get the library, but it did not work.

Comment: It's important that you invoke the M-x nrepl-jack-in when a buffer is open that is part of the project. Either a dired buffer of the project folder with the project.clj in it or any file within that folder or subfolders. (Edit: The keys you mentioned for compiling and switching the namespace should work on any source file that is part of the project and compiles flawlessly.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

here is an example of a properly configured project to compare with:

project.clj:

```
(defproject math-example "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"                            
  :description "FIXME: write description"                            
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"                                    
  :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"                           
            :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}        
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.5.1"]                       
                 [org.clojure/math.numeric-tower "0.0.2"]])
```

src/math_example/core.clj:

```
(ns math-example.core                                                
  (:require [clojure.math.numeric-tower :as math]))                  

(def x (math/expt 2 10))
```

repl:

```
math-example.core> (math/expt 2 10)                                  
1024                                                                 
math-example.core> x                                                 
1024                                                                 
math-example.core>
```

Using most clojure libraries should, in general, be no harder than adding the dependency and adding a `:require` tag to a namespace (or a `:use` tag if you prefer).

Comment: Great, thanks. This works. The only thing I don't understand is the `#<Namespace math-example.core>`. When I enter that I get an error. I used the instructions here http://clojure-doc.org/articles/tutorials/emacs.html#using-the-repl to get the namespace to REPL

Comment: that was printed when I hit ctrl-c alt-n from emacs to switch the repl to that namespace. I didn't actually type it. the equivalent would have been (in-ns 'math-example.core). I have deleted it from the answer.